# How do a conververtion with 1.0E-7 (Scientific Notation Converter)

Tags: kotlin

Is there a group of numbers bigger than E-6 decimals?

I'd like to make this simple conversion to decimal with a number E-7 Eg: 8.839E-7

```kotlin
val c = BigDecimal("8.4805E-6")
println(c)

val a = BigDecimal("8.839E-7")
println(a)
```

The first println are correctly: **0.0000084805**

The second was not converted: **8.839E-7**

Does anyone can help-me?

Answer (score 6):

There is a specific formatting algorithm used by `toString()` you can read about in the BigDecimal documentation.

If you want the number without any scientific notation, use `toPlainString()`:

```
println(a.toPlainString())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's converted correctly, it just displays this BigDecimal in this form because BigDecimal.toString() method works this way, from docs:

> Otherwise (that is, if the scale is negative, or the
> * adjusted exponent is less than {@code -6}), the number will be
> * converted to a character form using exponential notation.

I would suggest to use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format your BigDecimal to String